# Regex for numbers

Tags: java, regex

Im trying to create a regex of numbers where 7 should appear atleast once and it shouldn't include 9

```
/[^9]//d+
```

I'm not sure how to do make it include 7 at least once

Also, it fails for the following example

123459, it accepts the string, even tho, there is a 9 included in there

However, if my string is 95, it rejects it, which is right

Comment: `7` is just the regex for containing a 7

Comment: but 7 can be anywhere tho

Comment: Are you trying to match this number from within a larger string, or does your input consist of only the number?

Comment: input only consists of number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it would be to use several lookaheads:

```
(?=[^7]*7)(?!.*9)^\d+$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/ABPuPV/1).

---

Note that you need to double escape the backslashes in `Java`, so that it becomes:

```
(?=[^7]*7)(?!.*9)^\\d+$
```

Answer (score 3):

### Code

#### Method 1

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/OUE0ZH/2)

```
(?=\d*7)(?!\d*9)\d+
```

#### Method 2

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/OUE0ZH/4)

```
\b(?=\d*7)[0-8]+\b
```

**Note**: This method uses fewer steps (170) as opposed to **Method 1** with 406 steps.

Alternatively, you can also replace `[0-8]` with `[^9\D]` as seen [here](https://regex101.com/r/OUE0ZH/3), which is basically saying don't match `9` or `\D` (any non-digit character).

You can also use `\b(?=[^7\D]*7)[0-8]+\b` as seen [here](https://regex101.com/r/OUE0ZH/6), which brings the number of steps down from 170 to 147.

#### Method 3

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/OUE0ZH/5)

```
\b[0-8]*7[0-8]*\b
```

**Note**: This method uses few steps than both methods above at 139 steps. The only issue with this regex is that you need to identify valid characters in multiple locations in the pattern.

---

### Results

#### Input

```
**VALID**

123456780
7
1237412

**INVALID**

9
12345680
1234567890
12341579
```

#### Output

**Note**: Shown below are strings that match.

```
123456780
7
1237412
```

---

### Explanation

#### Method 1

- `(?=\d*7)` Positive lookahead ensuring what follows is any digit any number of times, followed by `7` literally
- `(?!\d*9)` Negative lookahead ensuring what follows is **not** any digit any number of times, followed by `9` literally
- `\d+` Any digit one or more times

#### Method 2

- `\b` Assert the position as a word boundary
- `(?=\d*7)` Positive lookahead ensuring what follows is any digit any number of times, followed by `7` literally
- `[0-8]+` Match any character present in the set `0-8`
- `\b` Assert the position as a word boundary

#### Method 3

- `\b` Assert the position as a word boundary
- `[0-8]*` Match any digit (except 9) any number of times
- `7` Match the digit `7` literally
- `[0-8]*` Match any digit (except 9) any number of times
- `\b` Assert the position as a word boundary

Answer (score 0):

If I find out correctly, you need a regex that accept all numbers that include at least one 7 and exclude 9. so try this:

```
(?:[0-8]*7[0-8]*)+
```

If you want found only numbers in a normal text add \s first and last of regex.

Comment: zero ?  It matches even for non-numbers

Answer (score 0):

This has got a bit complex but it works for your use case :

```
(?=.*^[0-68-9]*7[0-68-9]*$)(?=^(?:(?!9).)*$).*$
```

First expression matches exactly one occurence of 7, accepts just numbers  and second expression tests non-occurence of 9.

Try here : https://regex101.com/r/5OHgIr/1